# PostgreSQL Fetch by dates that doesn't exists in jsonb item in another table

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables in mypostgres database: parkingplaces where I have all the places that I want to fetch, and a second table where there are date ranges(in jsonb[] format ) that cannot be selected if the date given by user is contained in these date ranges (which contain a start date, end date and a range of hours)

```
CREATE TABLE parkingplaces
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('parkingplaces_id_seq'::regclass),
    namePlace character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT parkingplaces_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

AND

```
CREATE TABLE parkingblockedtimeslots (
        id SERIAL UNIQUE,
        idplace character varying,
        timeslot jsonb[],
        PRIMARY KEY (idplace)
        );

     id | idplace |  timeslot                                                                                                                                                                      
      9 | 140     | {"{\"end\": \"2020-10-09\", \"slot\": \"[08-12h, 12-16h]\", \"start\": \"2020-10-09\"}","{\"end\": \"2021-01-07\", \"slot\": \"[08-12h, 20-00h]\", \"start\": \"2021-01-05\"}","{\"end\": \"2021-02-25\", \"slot\": \"[08-12h, 20-00h]\", \"start\": \"2021-02-09\"}","{\"end\": \"2021-02-25\", \"slot\": \"[08-12h, 20-00h, 00-04h, 04-08h]\", \"start\": \"2021-02-09\"}"}
```

Given a date, I want to select all the places in the parkingplaces that doesn't have an entry in the parkingblockedtimeslots that contains this date

It will look like this

```
  select * from parkingplaces p where NOT EXISTS 
    (select * from parkingblockedtimeslots b WHERE b.idplace  = p.id AND [date] BETWEEN EACH ITEM in the jsonb[] )
    \\ [date] must be between start - end and also in the range of hours (slot item)
    \\ If startdate == enddate in the jsonb item ->   [date] must between the range of hours of this day
    \\ If enddate > startdate in the jsonb item ->   [date] must between the range of hours of each day
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Don't use a json array for the `timeslot`s. Instead, normalise your schema, and use a `tstzrange` (or just two timestamps). That will make the query trivial, and it will allow you to build proper indices to make it fast.

Comment: Can I make a json array of tstzrange. For example, the user will book between 15 October and 15 November but only between the hours 06 - 12H. If I don't make a jsonb array, I will have something like this [2020-10-15 06:00, 2020-10-15 12:00]\n[2020-10-16 06:00, 2020-10-16 12:00] \n [2020-10-17 06:00, 2020-10-17 12:00].....[2020-11-15 06:00, 2020-11-15 12:00]. You can imagine the number of entries in my database if the user select a range of year.

Comment: Oops, I was missing that you have a matrix of date ranges and hour ranges. The `tstzrange` (or maybe just a `daterange`) would only be used for the date ranges. The hour slots need to be stored additionally, possibly in a `jsonb` array but maybe more suitably in an `intrange[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> second table where there are date ranges (in jsonb[] format)

I would start with normalising that database schmema. Instead of storing an array of objects for each place (already in a separate table at least), better store each object in its own row:

```
CREATE TABLE parkingblockedtimeslots (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        idplace integer REFERENCES parkingplaces(id),
        timeslot jsonb
);
```

```
 id | idplace |  timeslot                                                                                                                                                                      
  9 | 140     | '{"end": "2020-10-09", "slot": "[08-12h, 12-16h]", "start": "2020-10-09"}'
 10 | 140     | '{"end": "2021-01-07", "slot": "[08-12h, 20-00h]", "start": "2021-01-05"}'
 11 | 140     | '{"end": "2021-02-25", "slot": "[08-12h, 20-00h]", "start": "2021-02-09"}'
 12 | 140     | '{"end": "2021-02-25", "slot": "[08-12h, 20-00h, 00-04h, 04-08h]", "start": "2021-02-09"}'
```

Instead of storing `jsonb` objects, better store the values in individual columns of a suitable datatype. In this case, I'd suggest

```
CREATE TABLE parkingblockedtimeslots (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        idplace integer REFERENCES parkingplaces(id),
        valid_period daterange, -- use tstzrange for hours on start and end date
        hour_slots intrange[]
);
CREATE INDEX ON parkingblockedtimeslots USING gist (idplace, valid_period);
```

```
 id | idplace |   valid_period             |   hour_slots
  9 | 140     | '[2020-10-09, 2020-10-09]' | '{[8, 12), [12, 16)}'
 10 | 140     | '[2021-01-05, 2021-01-07]' | '{[8, 12), [20, 24)}'
 11 | 140     | '[2021-02-09, 2021-02-25]' | '{[8, 12), [20, 24)}'
 12 | 140     | '[2021-02-09, 2021-02-25]' | '{[0-4), [8, 12), [20, 24)}'
```

<sup>(Syntax of literal values might need work)</sup>

With this, your query will be

```sql
SELECT *
FROM parkingplaces p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM parkingblockedtimeslots b
  WHERE b.idplace  = p.id
   AND [date] <@ valid_period
   AND [hour] <@ ANY hour_slots
)
```